# What skills does a spy need?

Tags: espionage

The story is set at a facitiy to train future agents.
There is a group of new trainees, that have to be tested selected to either: "Fail" (they failed a test and are no longer able to participate) or one of the different fields (Forensics, Hostage, Inteligence gain, analysis, cyber, Air Force...)

One part of their Training are certain challanges or tests, the candidates have to pass:
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/67248/29535

The other part of the education, contains the trainig, in which they are coached and prepared for these exercises.

During their Education and Evaluation proccess, they have to learn certain skills, however this is not critical to the plot, it's more the setting of the academy in which the storie plays.

However, how would would a general education as a Special Agent/Spy... look like.

Similar to the FBI training in Quantico, but on a broader scale in terms of tasks to learn (general education of all fields, to determin, where the candidat fits in best). And the proccess is mor selective than that

If I were to train a group of spies or special/secret agents, what would I have to teach them?

The skills should be based in reality, however, there have to be some, that are interessting to watch that gives a little action to the plot.

You can Imagine a setting similar to [Quantico](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4428122/)

What would they need to know?
What are known skills from movies and TV series?

I'm looking for something similar as in the TV show Quantico or BBC's SPY or the Movies "Kingsman" or the trainings programm in "GI Joe" or "the recruit".

I'm not looking for a single answer, more for a collections of answers?

Comment: There is a delightful documentary on spy work called 'Dr. No.'

Comment: Are you asking for a fictional spy such as Mr. Bond, or for a real-life spy such as [Richard Sorge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Sorge) or [Sidney Reilly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Reilly)? Starting with the Wikipedia article on [espionage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espionage) will get you a lot of good info. For a very good science-fiction approach you may want to look up  Eric Frank Russell's _[Wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasp_(novel))_.

Comment: I'm asking for a fictional one, but based in reality.

Comment: What does the spy actually **do**? For example, an "industrial" spy doesn't need any martial arts (?)

Comment: Just as an interesting aside, check out the [CIA's page for games for kids](https://www.cia.gov/kids-page/games).

Comment: BBC's spy is pretty good as well

Comment: What an individual needs to know is dependent on the task(s) the individual needs to perform. One doesn't need to know how to use firearms to steal secrets from a corporate building, nor does one need to know how to fly a plane to break into a prison. The knowledge needed is wholly character- and plot-based, making this off-topic. Write your spy/agent with the knowledge and skills necessary to fulfill your plot.

Comment: Ideally, they could [stare at goats](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1234548/) and other similar wizardry. :)

Comment: Here is some other info: [Stargate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Project)

Comment: If you get interested in CIA remote viewing, you might enjoy [Courtney Brown's "Cosmic Voyage"](http://courtneybrown.com/publications/CosmicVoyageByCourtneyBrown.pdf) in which he claims to have been part of the CIA's remote viewing project, which is what the movie "Men who stare at goats" was based on.

Comment: @ThomBlairIII This may sound pedantic. But the film *The Men Who Stare at Goats* was based on John Ronson's book *The Men Who Stare at Goats* (2004). Courtney Brown's book covered the same nutty squirrel brigade territory. More can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Men_Who_Stare_at_Goats

Comment: @a4android Sorry if I conveyed it was the same book. I just meant the movie based on was the CIA's remote viewing program and so was Brown's book. Sorry for an ambiguous statement.

Comment: @ThomBlairIII That's OK. It's too easy to fall into traps of ambiguity. There are several books on the CIA remote viewing program. Jim Schnabel wrote one too. He's good at investigating human weirdness.

Comment: I thought about closing as Too Broad or Off Topic, but @faerindel gave such a spot-on, direct answer that even addresses world building, I'd rather that answer be accepted!

Comment: Discretion: don't leave home base without it ;)

Comment: There is a 4-season series called The Americans ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Americans_(2013_TV_series) ), talking about the life of two high-level Russians spies during the cold war.

Comment: Look good in black. Source: A bit of Fry and Laurie

Comment: Frezzley, I've noticed you've had several questions posted here.  Most of them have been having troubles for the same sort of reason.  I encourage you to either use the [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to craft questions that better meet WorldBuilding's standards, or hop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) and talk with people about what you need.

Comment: Thank you, this has been the most useful comment so far. I didn't know about sandbox. Can I move my question over there? @CortAmmon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**How to encode and send the information they gather, and when.**

That's it. Maybe the local language if you want to skyrocket the risk by sending a foreigner.

The best real spies live very dull, boring and standard lifes, have an according personality and a very civilian skillset. They are so uninteresting they raise no suspicions, ever.

But of course, they are boring by definition. That's bad for stories that aren't day-to-day-with-a-surprise or biographies of real spies (which are interesting because they risking their *real* neck against the *real* Nazis, for example).

If you are thinking of James Bond, he's actually more of a super-commando with a battleship-grade plot armor. His skills are whichever he needs to have in that moment.

Comment: As far as I can tell, most real-life spies are recruited because they are in a position that has access to information the spying entity wants.  They are either offered money, or do the spying for ideological reasons.  So the skills a future spy needs is basically whatever will let them get a sensitive job.

Comment: Yes, even if deliberately training someone for infiltration as a spy you would focus on the "job skills". Trying to insert a spy in enemy military to be useful a decade later - don't train commando skills, but planning and logistics to get him a staff officer job pushing potentially sensitive documents. Trying to get enemy secret weapons - inflitrate the spy as a CAD draftsman or network administrator, so you'll train them for that job and engineering skills to know which data matters. Also, worth to note, all those missions are measured in years at least, not like James Bond short term trips.